# How can I perform a rebase with pygit2?

Tags: python, git, pygit2

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21661211) touches on how to perform a merge with `pygit2`, but, to the best of my understanding, that will result in a new commit.  Is there a way to perform a rebase, which will not result in a new commit and will simply fast-forward the branch reference to correspond to the latest from a given remote?

Comment: that's not, strictly speaking, a rebase. That's a fast-forward merge.

Comment: @WayneWerner yes, you're right.  I'll need to play around with `pygit2` to apply the changes on current branch *on top of* the latest state from the same branch on a remote.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can fast-forward with [Reference.set_target()](http://www.pygit2.org/references.html#pygit2.Reference.set_target).

Example (fast-forwarding `master` to `origin/master`, assuming that the script starts from checked out `master` branch in clean state):

```
repo.remotes['origin'].fetch()
origin_master = repo.lookup_branch('origin/master', pygit2.GIT_BRANCH_REMOTE)
master = repo.lookup_branch('master')
master.set_target(origin_master.target)

# Fast-forwarding with set_target() leaves the index and the working tree
# in their old state. That's why we need to checkout() and reset()
repo.checkout('refs/heads/master')
repo.reset(master.target, pygit2.GIT_RESET_HARD)
```

Comment: will [repo.lookup_branch('origin/branch1',GIT_BRANCH_REMOTE)](http://www.pygit2.org/references.html#pygit2.Repository.lookup_branch) actually fetch the latest state from remote ('origin' in this case)?

*edit*: markdown

Comment: @Piotrek No, `lookup_branch()` doesn't fetch. You must `fetch()` explicitly. See updated answer.