# How to rebase with pygit2?

Tags: python, git, pygit2

I'm stuck trying to implement a `git rebase` with `pygit2`.

Assuming this repo history, how to rebase `topic` on `master` using `pygit2` ? (ie, the equivalent of `git rebase master topic`):

```
      A---B---C topic
     /
D---E---F---G master
```

According to [pygit2 documentation](http://www.pygit2.org/recipes/git-cherry-pick.html#cherry-picking-a-commit-without-a-working-copy), `merge_trees` can be used to this end. So far, I got:

```
import pygit2 as git

repo = git.Repository(".")

master = repo.lookup_branch("master")
topic = repo.lookup_branch("topic")

base = repo.merge_base(master.target, topic.target)

master_tree = repo.get(master.target).tree
topic_tree = repo.get(topic.target).tree
base_tree = repo.get(base).tree

index = repo.merge_trees(base_tree,topic,master)
tree_id = index.write_tree(repo)

sig = git.Signature('FooBar', 'foo@bar.org')

# this is not going to work -> several commits need to be re-created
repo.create_commit(topic.name,sig,sig,"msg?",tree_id,[master.target])
```

This fails with the error `GitError: failed to create commit: current tip is not the first parent`.

Other SO questions ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38577476/how-can-i-perform-a-rebase-with-pygit2) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21661211/how-to-make-a-git-merge-by-pygit2)) discuss fast-forward merges but not proper rebase.